# 3 Digits - Non Repeating Permutations - From Array of X elements

Tags: c++

im trying to make a working program which has to go throught all the 3 digits permutations from a given array of X elements and in every loop sum all the 3 digits and compare it to given number the next rule which is being applied is : sum of any 2 numbers from given permutation must be > than the 3rd number in the permutation

what i tried:

```
for (int q = 0; q < sizeofarray; q++) 

 for (int w = 0; w < sizeofarray; w++) 

  for (int e = 0; e < sizeofarray; e++){

compare_digits_from_permutation_to_given_number

(givennumber,array[q],array[w],array[e]);


}
```

my code absolutely doesnot work , this is just the part which should do the thing that i am asking about , but it do permutations just of the first 3 elements , the array is dynamic i also dont have idea how to do that , sum of any 2 numbers must be more than the 3rd side

Comment: I tried to compile, but there is a lot of code missing.  Please edit your post so it compiles.

Comment: What is array[q], array[w], array[e]? What is compare_digits_from_permutation_to_given_number?

Comment: Please don't remove the original question with anew comment.  This site preserves questions and answers so that future viewers ma benefit from the help you received.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged you question as C++, I would suggest to use build-in `std::next_permutation()` :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3}
    do {
        compare_digits_from_permutation_to_given_number(givennumber,v[0],v[1],v[2]);
    } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

Comment: This would do permutations of all the iterators from `begin()` to `end()` (or any other iterators). You can easily extend it to array of n elements.

Comment: @josh31 these are not permutations then.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> v, int n)
{
#if 1 // remove duplicate input, so with {3, 3, 3, 4, 5},
      // the triplet (3, 4, 5) is shown only once.
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
#endif

    for (const auto& e1 : v)
    {
        for (const auto& e2 : v)
        {
            if (e2 == e1) {
                continue;
            }
            for (const auto& e3 : v)
            {
                if (e3 == e1 || e3 == e2) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (e1 >= e2 + e3 || e2 >= e1 + e3 || e3 >= e1 + e2) {
                    continue;
                }
                const auto total = e1 + e2 + e3;
                std::cout << e1 << "+"  << e2 << "+"  << e3 << "=" << total;
                if (total < n) {
                    std::cout << " is less than " << n << std::endl;
                } else if (total == n) {
                    std::cout << " is equal to " << n << std::endl;
                } else {
                    std::cout << " is more than " << n << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/EyMmY7)